# Javascript - array.map match index

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

There's an array looking as follows:

[[3,0], [6,0], [2,0], [9,0]....]

I'm trying to create a React/Redux reducer that changes the value of one of the 0s to 1. I click on an element and an action is dispatched. Idx is the index of an element in an array (eg. 0, 1, 2, 3)

```
export const toggleTile = (idx) => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_TILE,
    idx
  };
};
```

The reducer below does not work as I'd like it to be. I just created the skeleton of the conditional statements. If I click on a tile with index 3 (so the fourth tile), it changes the [n,0] to [n,1] for all elements. First of all it should only do if I click any of the tiles, and it should change [n,0] to [n,1] only for the clicked tile so I'm trying to change the 3 in the code below to the index of an 'i' element being mapped.

```
export default (state = [], action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_GRID:
      return action.payload || [];
    case TOGGLE_TILE:
      return state.map((i) => {
        if (action.idx === 3) {
          return (i[1] === 0
            ? [i[0], parseInt(i[1], 10) + 1]
            : [i[0], parseInt(i[1], 10) - 1]
          );
        }
        return [i[0], i[1]];
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

A grid component:

```
export default class Grid extends Component {
  render() {
    const mygrid = [];
    this.props.inGrid.forEach((r, i) => {
      mygrid.push(
        <Square
          key={i}
          idx={i}
          sqValue={r}
          toggleTile={this.props.toggleTile}
        />
      );
    });
    const { grid } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={grid}>
        {mygrid}
      </View>
    );
  }

}



export default class Square extends Component {

  myaction() {
    this.props.toggleTile(this.props.idx);
    console.log(this.props.idx);
  }

  render() {
    const { square, textStyle, squareActive } = styles;
    const { sqValue } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={[square, sqValue[1] && squareActive]}
        onPress={this.myaction.bind(this)}
      >
        <View>
          <Text style={textStyle}>{sqValue[0]},{sqValue[1]}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Is this "[[3,0], [6,0], [2,0], [9,0]....]" what "state" is in the line return state.map((i) => {

Comment: yes, it is the state returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this, with varying degrees of verbosity (due to Redux's insistence on immutability), but here's a pretty straightforward one:

```
case TOGGLE_TILE:
  const nextValue = state[action.idx].slice(); // Make a copy of the tuple to be toggled
  nextValue[1] = nextValue[1] === 0 ? 1 : 0;   // Toggle it

  const nextState = state.slice();             // Make a copy of the state
  nextState[action.idx] = nextValue;           // Replace the old tuple with the toggled copy
  return nextState;
```

Or:

```
case TOGGLE_TILE:
  const prevValue = state[action.idx];
  const nextState = state.slice();
  nextState[action.idx] = [ prevValue[0], prevValue[1] === 0 ? 1 : 0 ];
  return nextState;
```

Comment: Thanks - simple - I thought you always map over the array when returning a new state.

Comment: `map` is often the most convenient because it always returns a new array (thus ensuring you don't mutate the original), but if you're only changing one item it's overkill IMO. If you don't use `map` you need to use `slice()` to make a copy, as on line 5 above (and of course be careful not to mutate any child objects, ergo the additional `slice()` on line 2).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a second solution that's somewhere between my first solution and yours. Neither is really any better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm gonna try and see what we can do with just the following portion of code you shared.

I would like to note that the code presented is not succinct. It would be a great benefit to yourself, your team, as well as anyone here on this site if your code was refactored the more you understand what you need to build.

```
// So state is just an array of arrays...

var state = [3,0], [6,0], [2,0], [9,0]];

return state.map((i) => { // i => [3,0] or [9,0] !! i is not index !!
// Map is going to iterate over the entire array of arrays.

  if (action.idx === 3) {
  // action.idx is what comes in from the click.

    // Here is where your doing your work.
    // If the first element of "i" is zero, then 
    // return the same array but add 1 to the second element of array.
    // so [3,0] or [4,0] should become [3,1] or [4,1] but only for #3 as 
    // action.idx === 3 says to only change when... Nope, this is not how it will work. You need your exception in the MAP.
    return (i[1] === 0 ? [i[0], parseInt(i[1], 10) + 1] : [i[0], parseInt(i[1], 10) - 1]);
    }

  // ?? Why don't you just return i, as i is each array of numbers.
    return [i[0], i[1]];
  });

// It seams to me that something like this should work, just plug and play.
// I am assuming a few things here that I will spell out. If they are incorrect, let me know and I'll change it.

// state will be an array of arrays that only contain two numbers each.
// They may or may not be in original order.
// The second element of each array will be either 0 or 1.

var state = [3,0], [6,0], [2,0], [9,0]];

state.map(function(cell){ // call it what you want, you called it "i".
  if(cell[0] === action.idx){ // If clicked action index is === to cell[0]
    // You could just hard code 3 as you did above, but this makes it dynamic.
    // and only changes the cell that was clicked.
    cell[1] = cell[1] ? 1 : 0; // if cell[1] is 0, then it is falsey, no need for complex logic. No need to parseInt if they are numbers to begin with. But if you do, then use "+" to change a string to number.
  }
  return cell;
});
```

> Without notes

```
var state = [3,0], [6,0], [2,0], [9,0]];

state.map(function(cell){
  if(cell[0] === action.idx){
    cell[1] = cell[1] ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return cell;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments - taken on board.

Comment: Your solution mutates the original (sub)arrays, which is strictly forbidden in Redux.

Comment: Your right it's against redux behavior. I was going for the answer to members question in general, which was about map behavior.